# Best way to GET the default Image for Magento 2 using the Rest API

Tags: magento2, product-images

This seems simple but I see a few options for pulling images using /V1/products/{sku}. One is the media_gallery_entries which works fine other than the fact that the first image is not always the default image.

I see under custom_attributes there is

```
{
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/1/8/18so03801-blu_1143_front_6.jpg"
}
```

I also see an array of "types" nested inside of the media_gallery_entries

```
"types": [
        "image",
        "small_image",
        "thumbnail"
      ]
```

Which makes more sense to use but my question is:

Is this available by default for ALL instances as I could not find any documentation on this, and if not is there a better way to get the default image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the types are available for all instances when using

'productRepositoryFactory'

By specifying the type:

```
$product->getData('small_image');
```

You'll be able to get the default image for a specified product SKU for example.